# best way to display images android?

Tags: c#, android, image

I am developing an android application and I have to display images in it. This image is uploaded from a c# application and I need to retrieve it to android client.

I am trying by loading the image into the DataBase and retrieveing it from android, but this takes much memory and I need a better way to do it.

This c# application is allocated into the server so maybe a good way is to store the images and access to the path from the android client, but is it possible to public an image in my server?

Further, which one you think is the best way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly: You upload a picture using a C# program which stores the image (as binary data) in the database?

I would recommend to store the image on the filesystem and the (relative) path to the image in the database. Your Android clients get the URL of the picture and can download and display the image.

There are (very good) Android libraries for displaying images from URLs. Take a look at this library: [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

Comment: Android Univeral Image Loader, nuff said!

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to store image file to server, and add its path to database.

The easiest ways to display image in your android app is using Picasso Library.

Download Picasso library from [here](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Add it to your build path. Import this library to your code file.

For loading image from web url:

```
String url = "http://example.com/image.png"
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url).into(imageView);
```

For loading image from drawable:

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.imageFile).into(imageView);
```

Here, imageView is the name of variable you are using to represent ImageView. Eg.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
```

To use Picasso with ImageButton, change imageView variable to imageButton variable

```
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
```